# Two way communication from the file that run with exec in child

Tags: c, operating-system, pipe, fork, exec

I am creating a child process with a fork in program y. In that child, I run another program with exec, in which I want the function in that program (let's call it program x) to return something to me. Is there a way to pass this returned value to the parent?
I provided some sort of a pseudo-code that demonstrates what I want to do below.

program.x:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    if(argc != 2)
    {
        printf("argument count does not match\n");
        return -1;
    }

    printf("task1!\n");
...
    char *value = "want this"; // how to pass this to the parent in the program y?
...


}
```

program y:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int fd[2];
    pipe(fd);
    pid_t p;
    p = fork();
    if(p==-1)
    {
        printf("There is an error while calling fork()");
    }
    if(p==0)
    {
    printf("We are in the child process\n");
    printf("Calling hello.c from child process\n");
    char *args[] = {"Hello", "C", "Programming", NULL};
    execv("./hello", args);
    close(fd[0]);
    write(fd[1], ???, ??);
    close(fd[0]);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("We are in the parent process");
        wait(NULL);
        close(fd[1]);
        read(fd[0], ???,???);
        close(fd[0]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The only thing you can pass directly is the exit code of the child (via `wait()`).

To pass a string between two processes, you need an IPC data structure like pipes. See the `pipe()` function in `unistd.h`.

Comment: i actually am using pipes, like `pipe(fd)`. or am i wrong?

Comment: True. But you don't use the pipe in the child process.

Comment: how can i open a pipe between my child and program x, should be my question then, i think

Comment: The pipe is already open; you inherit it from the parent. You just have to write to it.

Answer (score 0):

For the simple case where there is one-way communication from a child to a parent), you can use `popen`. It's high level, simple to use, and has little overhead (if any) over fork/exec

```
int main(...)
{

   ...
   FILE *fp = popen("./hello 'Hello', 'C', 'Programming'", "r") ;
   char resp[200] ;
   if ( fgets(resp, sizeof(resp, fp) ) {
      // Do something
   }
   int result = pclose(fp) ;
}
```

Note that the way to pass command line arguments follows shell rules - arguments may need to be quoted (usually, single quote) to pass any special characters.

The 'pclose' result is the exit code of the executed program.